# Web API gets SQL network connection error after a few hours of running

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Blazor app that connects to an API. Both of them are on the same server (IIS).
Everything works fine, but after one or two days, when users try to log in, API returns this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found.

I tried to reset all the SQL server services (SQL Browser, SQLSERVERAGENT,... ), but it didn't work.
I also tried to restart my website and web API in IIS, but it didn't work.
The only thing that worked is restarting the server!
What's the problem? Why do we get this error after a few hours?

Comment: Do you correctly free your connections after accessing the database?

Comment: I'm using the UnitOfWork pattern with repositories. Everything works fine on my local IIS even after a week of running and testing. We haven't launched the application yet, and there aren't many requests to the main server, just me and a tester sending requests to it. This error occurs only on the server. Although the error occurs, I am able to access the database in Management Studio, and the database is not in a problematic state.

Comment: It's weird that even when I restart SQL Server services and my applications in IIS, the error persists. I must restart the server and then everything works fine!

Comment: Any graphics operations in your API ?

Comment: The error is *The network path was not found.* which suggests some sort of network layer issue, as does the fact that doing service starts doesn't solve the problem.  Check for network issues in the server logs.

Comment: Sometimes error messages can be misleading. If you `exec sp_who` or `exec sp_who2` on the SQL Server itself when this happens are there hundreds (or thousands) of connections open from your API? If so then it suggests that Connection Pooling isn't working in your API correctly, probably because the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` or `SqlDataReader` objects (which are `IDisposable`) aren't being correctly created and released.